# K8s metric server - pod telemetry update frequency too high

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubelet

**My set up**

I have one physical node K8s cluster where I taint master node so it can also act a worker. the node has Centos7 with total of 512 GB memory. I am limiting my experiments to one node cluster; once a solution is found, I will test it on my small scale k8s cluster where master and worker services are on separate nodes.

**What I am trying to do**

I want to monitor pod level resource utilization (CPU and Memory). I am launching a pod which consumed memory at rate of 1GBPS; in around 100seconds, memory utilization reaches 100GB and at that point application reaches steady state. From that point, it keep running until killed with a trigger.

**Where I am right now with this**

After launching k8s metric server; I am able to do `kubectl top pods` and it shows per pod CPU and memory utilization. However these utilization numbers are not updated frequently. I tried to measure how long does k8s takes to update these telemetry and sampling interval appears to be close to 1 minute or 60 seconds.

I tired looking into https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/ for figuring out various sampling intervals. there are a few parameters which could impact telemetry sampling rate; but they are set to ~20s (defaults) at max. I am not changing any Kubelet settings.

**My Question**

Why it takes around a minute for `kubectl top pods` to update resource utilization numbers.? how can I reduce this interval and have frequent updates.?

Answer (score 2):

- **Why it takes around a minute for `kubectl top pods` to update resource utilization numbers?**

  It's because metric server's default resolution which is set to 60s.
- **How can I reduce this interval and have frequent updates?**

  You can change the resolution with `--metric-resolution=<duration>` flag.
  It's not however recommended settings values below 15s as this is the resolution of metrics calculated by Kubelet.

  ```yaml
  spec:  
    containers:  
    - command:  
      - /metrics-server  
      - --metric-resolution=15s
  ```

  Reference: [How often metrics are scraped](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-often-metrics-are-scraped)